# Dealing with hrefs in an angularjs app meant for html5 and phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova

So I'm working on an AngularJS app that I'd like to put out as both a website and a phonegap app. For the web version, I'd like to use html5 mode, but for phonegap, that is obviously a problem, and from searching for quite a while it seems like no one has found a workable solution. I'd like to use one codebase for both, and I'm using grunt's preprocessor to add platform specific code (like taking the LocationProvider configuration out of the phonegap version.)

However, the two are incompatible in a very frustrating way--hrefs that work in one don't work in the other, and vice versa.  works in html5, while  doesn't, and the opposite for non-html5 mode.
Currently, the best solution I've thought of is pretty gross--writing links as  and then setting hash to either blank or # depending on the platform. This works, but it seems like a pretty poor solution.

Are there any better ways to manage links in a codebase meant to work in both modes? (Forcing 'HTML5 fallback mode' does not appear to work in phonegap.)